# Concatenar grandes strings

Tags: php

Estou tendo dificuldade a coluna `imagem` ao puxar dados no MySQL grande volume e a uma única linha possui `string` muito grande que é coluna `imagem` (Registro tem em torno 6.000-10.000 por remessa).

A coluna `imagem` possui dado de uma cópia de arquivo compactado em **ZIP** e convertido em `base64()` (Exemplo print abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fluxo: Carrega arquivos (**csv** ou **txt**) e **pdf** se houver, ao carregar arquivos é enviado para banco de dados, faz cópia dos arquivos **csv/txt** e **pdf**, compacta em **ZIP** do **pdf**, converte em `base64()` do arquivo **ZIP** e por final cria arquivo **XML** para ser enviado via **SOAP**.

Ou seja na parte de criar arquivo `XML` estou recebendo erro de memória, mesmo definindo para 600MB na função `ini_set()`.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 629145600 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 507512456 bytes) in
> /home/techgame/public_html/tools-cra/conf/function.php on line 80

O erro da linha 80 termina na parte `endwhile;` bem provável relacionado com MySQL.

```
<?php
    while($col = mysqli_fetch_array($titulo)):
        $xml .= '<tr t01="1" t02="555" t03="" t04="" t05="" t06="" t07="" t08="00000-000" t09="CUIABA" t10="SP" t11="'.$col['nossonumero'].'" t12="'.$col['especie'].'" t13="'.$col['numerotitulo'].'" t14="0" t15="'.$col['imagem'].'" t16="'.$rows.'"/>';
        $rows++;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Segue o Layout XML quando é montando antes de criar arquivo XML.

Obs.: Utilizando hospedagem, possui 1GB de RAM.

```
<?php
    function layoutXML($conn,$value){
        $comarca = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT comarca FROM remessa WHERE sequencial = '{$value}' GROUP BY comarca");
        $remessa = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM sequencial WHERE sequencial='{$value}'");
        $remessa = mysqli_fetch_array($remessa);
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><remessa><nome_arquivo> '.substr($remessa["arquivo_ref"],-12).' </nome_arquivo>';
        
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout',1000);
        ini_set('memory_limit','600M');
        
        while($municipio = mysqli_fetch_array($comarca)):
            $titulo = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM remessa WHERE sequencial='{$value}' AND comarca='".$municipio['comarca']."'");
            $xml .= '<comarca CodMun="'.comarca($municipio[0]).'"><hd h01="0" h02="555" h03="555" h04="'.data($remessa["data"]).'" h05="'.$value.'" h06="" h07="" h08="'.mysqli_num_rows($titulo).'" h09="0" h10="043" h11="'.comarca($municipio[0]).'" h12="" h13="1" />';
            $rows = 2;
            while($col = mysqli_fetch_array($titulo)):
                $xml .= '<tr t01="1" t02="555" t03="" t04="" t05="" t06="" t07="" t08="00000-000" t09="CUIABA" t10="SP" t11="'.$col['nossonumero'].'" t12="'.$col['especie'].'" t13="'.$col['numerotitulo'].'" t14="0" t15="'.$col['imagem'].'" t16="'.$rows.'"/>';
                $rows++;
            endwhile;
            $soma = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SUM(saldo) total FROM remessa WHERE sequencial='{$value}' AND comarca='".$municipio['0']."'");
            $soma = mysqli_fetch_array($soma);
            $xml .= '<tl t01="9" t02="555" t03="" t04="'.data($remessa["data"]).'" t05="'.(mysqli_num_rows($titulo)*3).'" t06="'.number_format($soma['total'],2,'.','').'" t07="" t08="'.$rows.'"/></comarca>';
        endwhile;

        ini_set('default_socket_timeout',60);
        ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

        $xml .= '</remessa>';
        return $xml;
    }

    function createXML($xml,$path){
        $fp = fopen($path,"w+");
        fwrite($fp,$xml);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    createXML(layoutXML($conn,"5000"),"bkp/xml/nome_arquivo.xml");
?>
```

Comment: Ao invés de fopen e fwrite porque não tenta file_put_contents (dentro do looping) ? Assim você não precisaria deixar  a variavel $xml com o conteúdo imenso que causa esse estouro de memória. Outra solução seria utilizar generator https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: Isso não me parece ter haver com o MySQL, mas sim com o próprio PHP e sua concatenação de string.

Comment: @MarcosXavier Obrigado pela informação, usei a sua sugestão `file_put_contents()` dentro do looping, obtive sucesso. Ao testar envio via SOAP não obtive sucesso quando arquivo é muito grande (torno 450-500MB). Sem imagem fica em torno 10MB, essa obtive envio sucesso. Utilizei `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: @Inkeliz Sim você está certo, não é relacionado com MySQL. Com informação de Marcos Xavier acabei entendendo o problema (E ganhando mais experiência tbm rs) que a variável `$xml` tava enchendo memória ou seja gerando estouro conforme o rapaz diz. De qualquer forma obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Show. Recomendo muito o entendimento/uso dos generators

Comment: @MarcosXavier Obrigado mais uma vez por falar sobre assunto generator. Achei muito útil a função `yield`.

Comment: @AugustoJunior, caso tenha achado uma solução para a pergunta pode adiciona-la. Talvez, pode alterar o titulo da pergunta para "como concatenar grandes strings" (ou similar), já que isto representa melhor o problema do que "MySQL grande volume". Claro, se quiser.

Comment: @Inkeliz editado amigo. Obrigado por orientar.